# How to run Mathematica on remote server

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have connected to a remote server using SSH. I would like to run Mathematica 8 which is installed on the server. When I type `mathematica` in the terminal, it says `Can't open display ""`. What should I do to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect to the server you need to use the -X option, e.g.

```
ssh -X user@servername
```